# asp.net mvc 4 linq extension method syntax join

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
 var model = _db.Seuni
                .Join(from o in _db.Keuni
                      join
                      c in _db.Seuni 
                      on o.klasaid equals c.klasaid
                          select new {o.emriklases,c.emristudent,c.studentid,c.nota })
                       .OrderByDescending(r => r.nota)
```

I have this sample of code,I have searched to find the right syntax for this linq extension method ,and I haven't can sb give to me the right one?Thank You in advance

Comment: If you can't use method syntax, why don't you use query syntax? It's much more readable if it comes to joins. If you need to use a method that isn't supported in query syntax split it into two queries. Due to LINQ's deferred execution it's not less efficient.

Comment: I know but I am trying to find the extension method.I can't seem to find it nowhere.I need sb who has worked with this! @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed query and method syntax in a wrong way.

```
 var model = _db.Seuni
            .Join(_db.Keuni,
                  c => c.klasaid,
                  o => o.klasaid,
                  (c, o) => new { o.emriklases, c.emristudent, c.studentid, c.nota })
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.nota);
```

Or with query (method for order) syntax

```
// query syntax
var model = (from o in _db.Keuni
            join c in _db.Seuni on o.klasaid equals c.klasaid
            select new { o.emriklases, c.emristudent, c.studentid, c.nota })
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.nota);
```

Comment: Both of them are right. One is method syntax and the other one is query syntax. Use the one you find easier.

Comment: And BTW if you need joins with linq then possibly there is something wrong in your data design. You should seldom need join.

Comment: when I loop @foreach(var item in Model)
{   <tr>
     <th scope="row">@item.studentid</th> I want to print also the klasaName but when I do @item.....it does not print klasaName

Comment: Take it slowly. First try your Linq in LinqPad. Then create your view model and use it. Linq query syntax is one question, utilizing the results in razor is another.

Comment: Cetin What am I missing?even with your query It does not display the klasaname after the @item.

Comment: You don't even have klasaname in the result set.

Comment: I meant emriklases.Your syntax does not generate ant error but still I cant get it in my Razor..

Comment: You don't need to use method syntax in the second query. Order by descending is supported

Comment: You are using an anonymous type. I would create a type for the result and use that. Assuming you have created your type, something like: new MyType {emriklases = o.emriklases, ...} instead of just new {o.emriklases, ...}

Comment: I didnt want to create that.You mean create a new class to hold this right?

Comment: Yes, it is easier. @TimSchmelter yes you can use order by in query syntax if you like to.

Comment: It is not for ordering,its for displaying the emriklases in razor

Comment: Ordering note was to TimSchmelter, not you. For using razor you can check the tutorials.